# Spring Boot can't read some API responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm using Spring Boot to consume API. For some APIs, it works but for some others it fails returning 500 Internal Server Error. For example, when consuming this API https://quoters.apps.pcfone.io/api/random it works, but https://reqres.in/api/unknown/23 returns 500 error. To what can this be due?

My code is simple:

```
restTemplate.getForEntity("https://reqres.in/api/unknown/23", String.class)
```

Comment: it means server of `regres.in` had an internal error... you need to debug that server or at the very least take a look at logs

Comment: make sure URL should be up n running "https://reqres.in".

Comment: If i try it, i get a 404 (which is what should happen). If you get a 500, then most likely you have additional code, that changes the behaviour. Add those details, if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

A request to the error-causing URL responds with a `404 Not Found` status code. Please check if the server is serving on the given endpoint.

As for the `500 Internal Server Error`, what's happening is that upon receiving the 404 from the server, your `RestTemplate` is throwing a `RestClientException`, which is being converted into a response with the status code: 500. You can add explicit handling for this using `@ControllerAdvice`, which will allow you to have more control over the response status.

Here's a reference for ControllerAdvice in Spring: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Have you tried to access https://reqres.in/api/unknown/23 in browser? You will see that the link is accessible.

Comment: That is correct, the link is accessible but if you were to open the developer console on your browser, you will be able to see the response code for the request in the network tab, which in this case is 404. A server sending a 404 response can send a response body along with it which is what you are seeing on the screen, but from a client's perspective, a 404 response code is still an error which is how RestTemplate interprets it.

Comment: Ok I see. That's a weird way to work for Spring Boot. Is there no easier way to return the real status code?

Comment: If you're using RestTemplate, it might need some explicit handling. I just did a quick pass of the specifications of the methods that RestTemplate offers, and pretty much every method is bound to throw a RestClientException which you'll have to handle. Also handling these exceptions might not be a bad idea because if you are acting as a gateway while requesting to an upstream server, your response status might differ from the servers in case of an error. For example, if the server gives you a 500 ISE, you as a gateway might want to return a 502 Bad Gateway error to your clients

Comment: Here's a link of the Rest Template specifications : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html